# Is there a way to include an extra layer of information in the clouds of rain cloud plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The data I am trying to visualise consists of information on species in a certain location, in two different years: their respective trait values (ranging from 1 to 12) and their respective abundances (1 to 15).

Here is a simplified dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(Species.name = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
2L, 3L), levels = c("Spec1", "Spec10", "Spec11", "Spec2", "Spec3", 
"Spec4", "Spec5", "Spec6", "Spec7", "Spec8", "Spec9"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("2012", 
    "2013"), class = "factor"), Abundance = c(1, 1, 8, 1, 3, 
    2, 6, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Presence = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1), Trait.value = c(6, 4, 6, 9, 7, 10, 7, 4, 6, 8, 5, 
    6, 4, 6, 9, 7, 10, 7, 4, 6, 8, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -22L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and the packages I've used plus some small modifications to the df:

```
library(ggplot2, ggdist)

df$Species.name <- as.factor(df$Species.name)
df$Year <- as.factor(df$Year)
str(df)
```

I want to show how many species with certain trait values occur when, using rain cloud plots in R/ggplot2, which works. I would, however, like to integrate an extra layer of abundance-weighed species richness info in the cloud part of the plots. This is the basic rain cloud plot:

```
Trait_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = Trait.value)) +
  ylim(0, 12) +
  stat_halfeye(adjust = 0.5, justification = -0.2, .width = 0, point_colour = NA) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.12, outlier.color = NA, alpha = 0.5) +
  stat_dots(side = "left", justification = 1.1, binwidth = 0.25) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  theme_classic()
Trait_plot
```

[Trait_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NjKL.png)

I have tried multiple ways of including the abundance numbers, so that the cloud shows the sum of the abundances of the respective species with a certain trait value or, better even, the percentage of individuals in the location that has a certain trait value. I have tried functions such as stat_halfeye, stat_slab and stat_density, but none of those seems to work, see for example

```
Trait_plot_statdens <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = Trait.value)) +
  ylim(0, 12) +
  stat_density(data = df, aes(x = Year, y = Trait.value), position = "jitter") +
  #stat_halfeye(adjust = 0.5, justification = -0.2, .width = 0, point_colour = NA) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.12, outlier.color = NA, alpha = 0.5) +
  stat_dots(side = "left", justification = 1.1, binwidth = 0.25) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  theme_classic()
Trait_plot_statdens
```

[Trait_plot_statdens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFJJ3.png)

Does somebody have advice on how to add this extra layer of abundance information? That would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you intend to show the abundance of each Species?  Since the plots are distributions of all the species together, that might be the difficulty. The aesthetic could include something for Species, but then you'd need a layer that can use it, whereas  stat_halfeye doesn't seem to have a way to include that.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your question! What I would like to show is the relative abundances of species with a certain trait value in the cloud part of the plot - so it doesn't have to be per species.

Answer (score 0):

As a rough start, you could consider this.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Species.name, y = Trait.value, size = Abundance)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(Year))
```

[image]